# REST Which Media Type Uses references

Tags: java, rest, media-type

Where I can find a reference to which all data types come under certain media types?

For example, `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` can consume  a `String` or `MultivaluedMap` in Java.

I would like to such reference.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) is the registration authority which maintains a list of standardized media-types

Comment: Thanks but that do not say which input data types we can use for that Media Type. I need MediaType to all Input Types mapping as explained in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my own question. I am just putting it out here so that in future if anyone needs to refer can refer to it :
On the following oracle webpage refer to the table mentioned in section **'Using Entity Providers to Map HTTP Response and Request Entity Bodies'**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp22/index.html